# AttributeError in module

Tags: python

when I write my functions in `mymodule` and then `import` that show me this error:

```py
def goodbye(name):
    print(f'goodbye{name}')
def hello(name):
    print(f'hello{name}')

import mymodule
mymodule.goodbye('nika')
```

Run

```
mymodule.goodbye('nika')
AttributeError: module 'mymodule' has no attribute 'goodbye'
```

I checked it many times but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: You seem to be saying that `goodbye()` is in `mymodule.py`. What file is the `import` in?

Comment: please add the complete traceback!

Comment: Your code sample seems to be the `mymodule` code.  Why would it need to import itself?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want to do:

File 1: `mymodule.py`

```
def goodbye(name):
    print(f'goodbye {name}')

def hello(name):
    print(f'hello {name}')
```

File 2: `test.py`

```
import mymodule

mymodule.goodbye('john')
```

Run file 2 on the command line, so that it imports file 1 and uses a function in it:

```
python test.py
```

Result:

```
goodbye john
```